# dynamically replace a value within a range, and change the next closest value

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an elegant way to select columns that contain a value under 15, and if they do, i want to change it to 1. I also want to change the next closest number to  2. any suggestions would be great. I can subset accordingly but am stuck with dynamically adapting the next closest number

df i have

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,1,13,23,40],
                        'b': [89.87,1,12,4,8],
                        'c': [45,12,901,12,29]}).astype(float)
```

df i want

```
expected = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,1,1,2,40],
                        'b': [2,1,1,1,1],
                        'c': [45,1,901,1,2]}).astype(float)
```

Comment: The logical is not fully clear. Why is 901 not changed to 2? It is next to a changed number

Comment: @mozway i want to check for values column wise, not row wise. So for column C, there are two values '12', which should be changed to '1', and the next closest value is '29', which is changes to '2'. does that make sense? the first df is one that I have and the expected is the one that i would like. I will specify that in the blurb

Comment: thanks got it, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use masks and `mask`:

```
mask = df.lt(15)                    # values lower than 15
mask2 = df.eq(df.mask(mask).min())  # min values, excluding values below 15

df.mask(mask, 1).mask(mask2, 2)     # replacing mask with 1, mask2 with 2
```

output:

```
      a    b      c
0   1.0  2.0   45.0
1   1.0  1.0    1.0
2   1.0  1.0  901.0
3   2.0  1.0    1.0
4  40.0  1.0    2.0
```